# Saving GAN generated images

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am following the DC GAN tutorial of pytorch for generating synthetic images. I want to store generated after the last epoch individually.
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html
I am new to this. I don't know how to save these images individually in a folder on local drive. Please help me.

I am not able to save images after trying different solutions available online. As I am new to this, it is hard for me to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save the images individually like this:

```
 import os

 sample_dir = ‘samples’
 if not os.path.exists(sample_dir):
 os.makedirs(sample_dir)

 if(epoch == num_epochs-1 ):
 fake_fname = ‘fake-{0:0=4d}.png’.format(i)
 save_image(fake[i], os.path.join(sample_dir, fake_fname), nrow=1)
```